# Use python to get data table Visualization from elastic search

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana

How can I filter and summarize data in elastic search through python. I manually created a data table visualization through Kibana interface and downloaded it in .csv format. Now I want to do the same using python.

For example, if there are 10 variables in the index: `v1,v2,v3,.. v10`  then how to get a data table which can be described in sql as:

```
select v2, count(v2) 
from index 
where v1 = "some value" 
group by v2
```

Till now I am able to do this:

```
from elasticsearch5 import Elasticsearch
user = 'xxx'
password = 'xxx'
url = 'xxx'
command = "%s:%s@%s:9200" % (user,password,url)
x = Elasticsearch(command)
# Get the count of documents
num = x.count(index='my_index')['count']
# Get documents filtered by v1
my_docs = x.search(index="my_index",  body={"query": {"match": {'v1':'US'}}})
```

Now what I want is to select only variable `v2` from my_docs and also group by `v2` to get a count. Apologies that I don't know how to create a reproducible example without revealing the user credentials.

Comment: try to cycle on my_docs var, it is a json

Comment: @Lupanoide, while that may work, I have two problems - First: I do not want to download complete documents (each document in the actual data contain 150+ variables). Second: I am not familiar with json yet, though I am working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First: I do not want to download complete documents (each document in
  the actual data contain 150+ variables).

If you want to treat only few fields on your doc, you should use the `_source filter` before your query - [doc here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-request-source-filtering.html). For example to retrieve from your docs only the `v1` and `v2` fields :

```
body={
    "_source": ["v1", "v2"],"query": {"match": {'v1':'US'}}}
```

- Second: I am not familiar with json yet, though I am working on it.

You just try something like this:

```
for result in mydocs['hits']['hits']:
    print result["_source"]['v1']
    print result["_source"]['v2']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try as soon as I am back on my office intranet.

Comment: I'm glad to help. If you need some other information, just ask :-)

Comment: thanks it works, but I have more questions - I will ask by editing my question